# Get the DNS Suffix Search List in a Metro app

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

One of the restrictions for Metro apps is that they can't connect to localhost. We are creating an app which allows the user to connect to a server by entering an IP or host name, and some of our users may be tempted to use localhost (our other software that they are connecting to may run on the same machine as a desktop app for x86 machines). If you try to connect to localhost you get a general connection error as if it's not reachable, but that is a lie that the OS tells the app to prevent it from doing stuff it shouldn't be doing.

We want to provide a better error message for this case. To do that I'm trying to compare what the user entered to the various names of the local machine, which we get through NetworkInformation.GetHostNames(). That works fine in some cases, but it does not work in all cases. Consider this case: the user's machine is named "foo", its fully qualified name is "foo.bar.com", and the network search path ("DNS Suffix Search Path" in ipconfig's output) is "bar.com". The user types in "foo.bar.com". When we go through the list of host names we get "foo", but not "foo.bar.com". Therefore the test fails to catch this case, and the user gets the generic error instead of our custom error.

I am looking for a way to determine programmatically what the search domain list is so that I can add those variants to the list to compare against. However, I can not find an API in WinRT (using C#) to give me that information.

Answer (score 2):

Are you testing this on a domain-joined machine? If it's a domain-joined machine, GetHostNames() should return one of the 'DomainName' types with the fully qualified DNS of the local machine. Therefore, if the machine is domain joined to 'bar.com', you should see 'foo.bar.com' listed as one of the 'DomainName' types. The other 'DomainName' type being foo.local.

Comment: Good question. No, this machine is not on the domain. The code I already have works for machines that are part of the domain, but not for machines that are not part of the domain. If a non-domain machine is named "foo" then our DNS server apparently still resolves "foo.domain.suffix.com" to point to that machine, but that machine's network settings will only show its name as "foo". But the network settings also have a DNS search list that includes "domain.suffix.com".

This may just be an issue with our DNS configuration, but I fear that it may be common with customers as well.